# how can I use jquery to change the background-color of only the clicked on link

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are list of links, how can I use jquery to change the background-color of only the clicked on link and it back to the original  color if I clicked on another link ??

Comment: That depends on the structure of the markup that you did'nt post!

Comment: So you want the last clicked link to have highlighted? :-)

Comment: yes I  want last clicked link highlighted

Comment: And does that click open a new page, or the page remains the same?

Answer (score 3):

This should do that for you:

```
$("a").click( function(event)
{
    $("a").css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

​
In the real world, you would probably have those links inside a div or something, so it should be like:

```
<div id="divName">
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
​
<script language="javascript">

$("#divName a").click( function(event)
{
    $("a").css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps something basic like this?

```
$("#linkDivWrapper").on("click", ".linkClass", function () {
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#ccc'});
}); ​
```

Comment: Why would you need to delegate the event ?

Comment: so i don't have to initialize every instance of the "a" element on the page load only the wrapper

Comment: Makes sense for hundres of elements, or elements that might be replaced dynamically, and the binding will be faster on pageload, but you'll pay for it on every click.

Comment: only every click event in the wrapper...which should only be those links.   it was a best practice they emphasized at the jquery conference a few weeks ago...so I just prefer do it that way

Answer (score 1):

Very generally since there's no markup posted, and targeting all `<a>` elements and preventing the default action, as going to a new page will make highlighting the link pretty useless :

```
var elems = $('a'); //select all a elements, could use class instead;

elems.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); //add highlight class to clicked
    elems.not(this).removeClass('highlight'); //remove highlight class from others
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Check this jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/9R5CG/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul​​​​​​​​​​​​​​>​​​​​​​​
```

**Script:**

```
$("#menu li a").click( function(event)
{
    $("li a").css('background', '');
    $(this).css('background', '#f5c491');
});​
```

Hope this will helps you.